# The function plotRoughKMeans() is not found in RStudio

Tags: r

## Despite having installed the SoftClustering package in R, the console is notifying that the function plotRoughKMeans() is not found.

#### CODE:

```
ds = read.csv(file="C:/Users/Shantan Sawa/Documents/pima-indians-diabetes.data", header=FALSE, sep=",")
print(ds)

set.seed(7)
library(RoughSets)
dx = SF.asDecisionTable(ds, decision.attr = 9, indx.nominal = NULL)
print(dx)

rule = dx[,c(2,6,8)]

library(SoftClustering)

data.matrix(rule)

y = RoughKMeans_LW(rule,2,2,100,1.5,0.7)

plotRoughKMeans(rule, y$upperApprox, y$clusterMeans)
```

the error thrown is:

```
plotRoughKMeans(rule, y$upperApprox, y$clusterMeans)
Error in plotRoughKMeans(rule, y$upperApprox, y$clusterMeans) : 
  could not find function "plotRoughKMeans"
```

Comment: What makes you think such a function exists?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SoftClustering/versions/1.1502/topics/plotRoughKMeans

Comment: Please try to replace this line `plotRoughKMeans(rule, y$upperApprox, y$clusterMeans)` for `SoftClustering:::plotRoughKMeans(rule, y$upperApprox, y$clusterMeans)`

Comment: The function is documented but not *exported*, so can only be run with the package prefix. This could be a bug and should be reported to the maintainer.